# Loading multiple csv files at once and keep the column names unchanged

Tags: r, csv

I have a folder containing different csv files. Below is the picture showing the csv files. I would like to import all of them at once and name them in one go. Also, I would like to keep the column names unchanged.

[image]

```
Here is what I tried:
#Loading the data
filenames <- list.files(path="C:/Users/Juste/Desktop/Customs Data",
                    pattern="Imports 201+.*csv")

filelist <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)

#assigning names to data.frames
names(filelist) <- paste0("Imports_201",2:length(filelist))

#note the invisible function keeps lapply from spitting out the data.frames to the console
invisible(lapply(names(filelist), function(x) assign(x,filelist[[x]],envir=.GlobalEnv)))
```

When I tried this, it only imports the first five csv files, it leaves out “Imports 2017_anonymised”. Also the column names change the format. For example, column “Best country” becomes “Best.country”. How can I import all of the csv files and keep the column names unchanged?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `map()` from the `purrr` package and `read_csv()` from the `readr` package (note that it is written with an underscore). This way your column names don't get changed.

```
library(purrr)
library(readr)
map(filenames, read_csv)
```

or if you automatically want to concatenate the dataframes use

```
map_df(filenames, read_csv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't add comments because I don't currently have enough reputation on here to do so. However, I think your regex might be a little off for the import. Try `pattern = "^Imports\\s+201\\d_anonymised\\.csv$"`.

Regarding the "."s in the column names, I believe that by default, R's core data import commands add these where there are spaces. Otherwise you'll need to use backticks each time you want to refer to a column with space in its name. You could try setting `check.names = F` in you `read.csv()` function, as this is what calls `make.names()` to sanitize the column names upon data import. type `?make.names` to see what it's doing.